# Xcode 8 PassKit issue and crash on simulator.

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode8, passkit, wallet

I updated xcode 8 and having issue with PassKit framework integration.
here is my case:
If i'm running on simulator below iOS 10.0 with wallet capabilities disabled, i'm getting

> dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:
>       0x179e000 <+0>: int3
>   ->  0x179e001 <+1>: nop

and

> Symbol not found: _kABPersonAddressCityKey error log.

Note that i'm not using wallet in my project, and anything related to passkit as well. so just to solve issue i include PassKit framework.

So basically what i notice that Wallet capabilities and PassKit.framework in Link Binary With Frameworks depended to each other. Disable wallet and passkit will be removed from linked frameworks.

Anyone already had this issue, how you solve it? 
and how keep PassKit in linked frameworks without enabling wallet capabilities?

Thing is that with wallet enabled i'm getting certificate error when running on device, because it's require wallet switch enable on my developer account as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, that even if the "wallet" was enabled, Xcode gave me the error, thats its not there. Be aware that when ever you enable Wallet in App Id, your provision profile is invalidated. You need to generate a new one, and change Xcode to use the newly created one.

Comment: thanks for answer, this solved my issue, now i can run on both device and simulator without any changes in settings.

Furthermore i would like to know is it possible to use PassKit with enabling wallet capabilities.